# Redirect to home page after login seam 3

Tags: seam3

I have custom Authenticator and I want to redirect to home page after successfully authenticate in seam 3 . How can i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

The simplest way is to `return "/home.xhtml";` in your login action.

Comment: Is there a way with seam security to redirect if not logined in as JASS

Answer (score 1):

Other way is use navigation rule in faces-config.xml:

```
   <navigation-rule>
      <from-view-id>/loginPage.xhtml</from-view-id>
      <navigation-case>
         <from-action>#{authBean.login}</from-action>
         <from-outcome>success</from-outcome> 
         <to-view-id>/homePage.xhtml</to-view-id>
         <redirect/>
      </navigation-case>
      <navigation-case>
         <from-action>#{authBean.login}</from-action>
         <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome> 
         <to-view-id>/loginPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
         <redirect/>
      </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: yes i have put it on navigation rule like <from-action>#{identity.login}</from-action><form-action>#{true}</form-action><to-view-id>/home.xhtml</to-view-id> that is working fine but now how to check wheather user login or not before rendering view using seam security

Comment: In view you can use something like this for example: 
<h:dataTable rendered="#{identity.loggedIn}"  ...... >.....

If you wanna to restrict invocation methods by only logged users you can add @LoggedIn annotation on beans or methods